# webkitTransitionEnd not firing when using -webkit-animation

Tags: javascript, animation, css, webkit

What's the difference between -webkit-transition and -webkit-animation? For some reason the webkitTransitionEnd does not fire when I use -webkit-animation.

How can I do to find out when the animation finished using this code  http://jsbin.com/oveval/7/edit . I have attached an event listener to all elements thats animating but none of them fires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is there: http://jsbin.com/oveval/10/ . 
You need to use `webkitAnimationEnd` event. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/webkitanimationevent

(alerts don't seem to work on jsbin..)